# How to display down arrow symbol android?

Tags: android

I have Button in  my layout,in that I want to display a down arrow symbol. I defined the Button in a layout file How can I set the down arrow symbol to that button,

can anyone help, thanks in advance......

Comment: just download an icon from online and set it as a background of your button

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Android API guides on Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html), you can use an ImageButton.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow_icon"
    ... />
```

You can download the `down_arrow_icon` from a number of resources (like the [Google Material icons](https://design.google.com/icons/) page) or even create your own image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `android:drawableRight` property. Like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
```